# Docker Image command pythonreturning non-zero code

Tags: python-2.7, docker

So I'm trying to build a new docker image with Python2.7 and pip for python 2.7 however I'm getting a "The command '/bin/sh -c pip2 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1" error when trying to build the image.

```
FROM colstrom/python:legacy
MAINTAINER **REDACTED**
RUN pip2 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python2.7", "parser.py"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `COPY`/`ADD` or mount your data (at least `requirements.txt` and `parser.py`) into the container.

Assuming your Dockerfile resides at the root directory of your project:

```
FROM colstrom/python:legacy
MAINTAINER **REDACTED**
COPY . .
RUN pip2 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python2.7", "parser.py"]
```